# I can't receive Push Notification - I receive response "Resource Id #3"

Tags: php, objective-c, ios, notifications, push

I'm trying send push notifications, but the APNS send me this response: Resource id #3, so this mean that is missing topic, second apple documentation, right?
What is "topic"? What am I doing wrong?
I create the certificate again, but I think that it is not the problem. I don't know what is the "topic".

below is my server php:

```
<?php

$deviceToken = $_POST["deviceToken"];


// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'password';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
        'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
        $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo $fp;
echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => $message,
        'sound' => 'default'
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
{
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    echo $fp;
}   
else
{
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    echo $fp;
}
    

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);


?>
```

The server sends the message with sucess, but is like I said before... I receive the response of APNS:

Resource id #3.

What can it be?

EDITED

I fix it. The problem was the url... I changed to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com. That's URL of Development!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the resource error, because you echo a resource.

You do:

```
echo $fp;
```

In this case $fp is a resource, not a string

Comment: I removed and still not working. Show the $ fp is not influencing anything. The APNs receive my request and returns this message.